# Stopping the flicker of TableLayoutPanel

Tags: .net, vb.net

in an effort to stop the "flickering" or the slow draw of many nested TableLayoutPanels, I've created this class:

```
Public Class MyTableLayout
    Inherits TableLayoutPanel
    Public Sub New()
        Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've rebuilt my application, so now I see the custom control. I'm attempting to follow this guide: https://www.richard-banks.org/2007/09/how-to-create-flicker-free.html which recommends that since I have already TableLayoutPanels in my WinForm, that I should go into *.Designer.cs code-beside files and change the TableLayoutPanel references to the class I just created.

However, I'm not sure where to find .Designer.cs

Can anyone gently push me in the right direction please? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

[Edit] I found it! However, when I try to change:

```
Me.TableLayoutPanel41 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
```

to

```
Me.TableLayoutPanel41 = New System.Windows.Forms.MyTableLayout()
```

It has that very pleasant red line underneath it. MyTableLayout is the new control/class(?) that I've just created. How should I go about changing the references as per the guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designer files are created when you create a form, if you're using visual studio, look in the solution explorer, and make sure you have the "Show All Files" enabled (it's 2 to the right from the refresh circle icon). From there click the small arrow by the side and it should show a .vb and a .designer.vb. In the guide it says .cs because it is a C# guide, but at the end of the day it's all the same :P

Need any more help, just reply.

Comment: Okay, I think I found it! However, when I try to change "Me.TableLayoutPanel41 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()" to "Me.TableLayoutPanel41 = New System.Windows.Forms.MyTableLayout()" it has that red line under it. I think this is where I'm supposed to change it, but not sure how to do so. Would you be able to gently guide me?

Comment: Hi! your control doesn't reside under `System.Windows.Forms`, remove this and try again.

Comment: My hero! <3 Thank you! Marked as answer!

Comment: Shoot! Sorry! Last question, I'm so sorry! It worked for a second, but when I clicked on my Form1 designer (where I add controls), it changed all of the things to "Me.tblSortModule2 = New Form1.MyTableLayoutPanel()" instead of simply "Me.tblSortModule2 = MyTableLayoutPanel()" so now they all have red lines again. I can undo all of these, but now moving forward, it seems like I can never click into my designer again. Is there a way I can circumvent this?

Comment: Did you change both places in the designer? there is the line you put, and there should be a different line

Comment: I changed this line as well:     "Friend WithEvents TableLayoutPanel31 As TableLayoutPanel" because I thought this would be what was wrong, but it's still autochanging all of the lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142743/discussion-between-proninjacat-and-lolikols).